# How can I prevent delay of layer clipsToBounds at page transition

Tags: ios, swift

I have a page which has radius corners.
When the page appear, corners are not rounded at first. After seconds, corners become rounded.
I want to make corners rounded from at first.

I set properties to view at custom view's initializer.

```
class ModalView: UIView {

  init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)

     self.backgroundColor    = UIColor.whiteColor()
     self.clipsToBounds      = true
     self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
  }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    let customView = ModalView()
    customView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view = customView
  }

}
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: How and when does ModalView get added to its view controller?

Comment: I updated question, thank you.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. CustomView and ModalView are two different classes. They have nothing to do with each other. Maybe that is why your code is not working as you expect?

Comment: Sorry, it was just typo of snippet.
I updated view name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved.
The situation was like below. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UiB3.png)

So, I set cornerRadius to navigation controller's view.

```
self.navigationController?.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.navigationController?.view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not compile.

First, initWithCoder is missing, maybe you omitted it.

Secondly, in init you call super initWithFrame, which internally is calling again init, here is where the program crashes, i don't get how yours is working but this explains the delay.

And third, loadView is used for controllers purely made in code, if you have a xib you already have a view.

Four, UIViewController does not extend a UIView, i don't even understand what you wanted to do there, you can't redefine a class.

Comment: Thanx for your comment.
I'm Sorry. Actually, I did not intend to compile my code, but I just wanted you to understand my situation. So, It can't compile as you say...